# How do I prove $R(A)=(Ker(A^T))^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

Let $A:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ be a linear transformation. If $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^n.$ define $$W^\perp=\{y\in \mathbb R^n|\langle x,y\rangle=0  \text{ for all }  x\in W\}$$
Then which one of the following is true?

(a) $R(A)\subset (Ker(A^T))^\perp$

(b) $R(A)=(Ker(A^T))^\perp$

(c) None of the above

Attempt:- Claim:- $R(A)\subset (Ker(A^T))^\perp$

$z\in R(A)\implies \exists x\in \mathbb R^m: z=A(x)$

We know that $A^T:(\mathbb R^n)^* \to (\mathbb R^m)^*$. $W^*$ denotes the [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) of $W.$ Let So, $Ker(A^T)=\{g \in (\mathbb R^n)^*: A^T(g)=0\}.$ So, $(Ker(A^T))^\perp=\{g \in (\mathbb R^n)^*| \langle g, h\rangle =0,\forall h\in Ker(A^T)\}.$ Let $g\in Ker(A^T). $ We keed to prove that $\langle g, z\rangle=0 \iff \langle g, A(x)\rangle=0  $. I am not able to proceed. Please help me. It was a question appeared in NBHM Examination, India. How do I find this complicated answer quickly?

Comment: $$\langle g, z\rangle = \langle g, Ax\rangle = \langle A^Tg, x\rangle = \langle 0, x\rangle = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

You show that $Ker(A^{T})=R(A)^{\perp}$ and then you use that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you have for any subspace $W$ that $W^{\perp\perp} = W$.

$$y \in Ker(A^{T}) \Leftrightarrow \langle \underbrace{A^Ty}_{=o},x \rangle = 0\: (\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \langle y,Ax \rangle = 0\: (\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \langle y,z \rangle = 0\: (\forall z\in R(A))$$
$$\Leftrightarrow y \in R(A)^{\perp}$$

Now, you take the orthogonal complement of $Ker(A^{T})=R(A)^{\perp} \Leftrightarrow Ker(A^{T})^{\perp}=R(A)^{\perp\perp}= R(A)$.